# Why does my @lazy property crash, but if I make it non lazy it works?

Tags: swift

I have a problem with lazy properties. I thought I got them but maybe I didn't / maybe it is a bug

I have a lazy array in my class

```
@lazy var enteredRegions = Array<String>()
```

now In

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool
```

I have

```
 self.enteredRegions.append(clRegion!.identifier);
```

this crashes hard with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

NOW If I remove the @lazy:

```
    var enteredRegions = Array<String>()
```

all works

so.. whats up with this? :D my understanding was that `self.enteredRegions` would create it anyway

(I do this with a UIWindow and a CLLocationManager and that works as I thought)

Comment: `@lazy` is for expensive operations so it's not run until the property is called. Creating an array is not an expensive operation so you should not need the @lazy anyways. Additionally from all my testing @lazy only works with classes.

Comment: @AlexReynolds sounds plausible but either it shouldn't be allowed or it shouldn't crash

Comment: Yes but it's probably a retain count issue. So it may be allowed but since the retain count isnt incremented it's released hence the bad access. Also this isnt the purpose of @lazy properties. Nothing about an array is expensive. Many things are allowed that cause crashes because memory mgmt and runtime

Comment: @AlexReynolds That is one use for lazy yes, but there other also other uses. Apple's documentation states multiple uses: "Lazy properties are useful when the initial value for a property is dependent on outside factors whose values are not known until after an instance’s initialization is complete. Lazy properties are also useful when the initial value for a property requires complex or computationally expensive setup that should not be performed unless or until it is needed".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some trial, I found something quite odd.

First of all, if we wrap the var inside a class, it simply works:

```
class RegionManager {
    @lazy var enteredRegions = Array<String>()
}
```

In `AppDelegate`, I declared a `@lazy var regManager = RegionManager()`.

Then, in `application:didFinishLaunching:`, I modify and use the value, it works without spitting a word:

```
regManager.enteredRegions.append("New!")
println("Regions: \(regManager.enteredRegions)") // Regions: [New!]
```

After this, I tried to change to some *native* values, for example, `String`, `Int` and so on, they all fail.

So, my guess is that this strange behaviour is actually a bug of the compiler itself, it may be rooted in some optimization for *native* types, maybe there's a inner pool or what that apple doesn't tell us.