# Lazy Optional Property Always nil?

Tags: swift

Is there a reason that the following code always prints out nil?

```
class Foo
{
    @lazy var bar: Int? = 5
}

println(Foo().bar)
```

I would think that when the bar property is accessed it would be initialized to 5.

Comment: I changed `Int?` to `Int` and it works as expected. But I can't figure out why `Int?` is not working.

Comment: it seems the `@lazy` optionals will be inited with `nil` as fastest way in runtime, regarding the `nil` value is also allowed for those. however it can be a compiler issue because makes no sense to define a `@lazy` var as optional.

Comment: The code posted works for me in the playground in Beta 3 for me at least. How are you running the code? Are optimisations on?

Comment: @JosephLord this was behave differently in beta 2. beta 3 "fixed" the bug. but [check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24793283/642626).

Answer (score 1):

Sweeping aside why you'd want to do this, the issue here is that you need to provide a lazy property an initializer it can use when it is first called.  The correct way to author your above code is:

```
class Foo {
    lazy var bar = Int(5)
}

print(Foo().bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because bar is wrapped in an optional. You need to unwrap it first to use it. Either with the ! Operator or a if let statement.

Edit:

It seems that there is a bug when using `@lazy` with native types. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033759) question.
Remember that Swift hasn't reached 1.0 yet so the compiler can have some bugs and the language may change.

Comment: unwapping a `@lazy` var would crash the application. would you like to re-cosider your answer before downvote?

Comment: holex: Why would that even be legal then, or maybe that will change?

Comment: logically it does not make any sense of making a `@lazy` var as optional, regarding the point of the `@lazy` is: the object and its value is already determined, but it won't be instantiated until the first use. that is why I'm thinking that is a _beta_ compiler issue only.

Answer (score 0):

As in Xcode6beta-3 this bug is "fixed" and introduced a new "feature"

```
$ swift
Welcome to Swift!  Type :help for assistance.
  1> class Foo { @lazy var bar: Int? = 5 }
  2> var f = Foo()
f: Foo = {
  bar.storage = nil
}
  3> f.bar
$R0: Int? = 5 // working good
  4> f.bar = nil // use new "feature" to reset bar
  5> f
$R2: Foo = {
  bar.storage = nil
}
  6> f.bar
$R3: Int? = 5 // not sure is this what I want
  7>
```

`f.bar` does give you `5` now. It also introduced a "feature" that allow you to un-initialize `@lazy` variable by assign `nil` to it. Then next time you calling `f.bar` will give you `5` again.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: In Xcode 6.1.1, the following code

```
class Foo
{
    lazy var bar: Int? = 5
}

var foo = Foo ()
println(foo.bar)
foo.bar = 6
println(foo.bar)
foo.bar = nil
println(foo.bar)
foo.bar = 7
println(foo.bar)
```

produces the output

```
Optional(5)
Optional(6)
nil
Optional(7)
```

as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have a lazy optional property with an initial value (in my opinion). I would recommend to use a calculated property.

If you want it to be a read-only property:

```
var bar: Int {
    return 5
}
```

else

```
var bar: Int? {
    get {
        return 5
    }
    set {
        bar = newValue!
    }
}
```