# Swift EXEC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown when accessing array written to by a tap installed on an AVAudioMixerNode

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access

I need help fixing an elusive bug which has been plaguing me for over a month.

I know it is a lot of code to look at, but the methods that seem to be the root of the problem are the installReadTapOnPadMixer() and the updateVolumeData() methods.

I have a sampler app in Swift. In one of my ViewControllers the user can press a “pad“ and a loaded sound will play. I currently have it set up so that when the pad is pressed, the sound’s current volume will affect how brightly the pad is colored:

[image]

The problem is that once in a while my app throws:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x55555555555550)

Or is some cases the exception looks like this:

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9c9c3170)

Each of my pad’s model side consists of an array of AVAudioPlayerNodes connected to an array of AVAudioUnitVarispeed nodes. each of the varispeed nodes is then connected to a single AVAudioMixerNode which is in turn connected to the AVAudioEngine’s main mixer node.

So again, that’s:

AVAudioPlayerNode[] -> AVAudioUnitVarispeed[] -> AVAudioMixerNode -> main mixer node.

In order to get the current volume of any given pad on the model side I have a tap installed on each of the mixer nodes in the chain. Like so:

/** ui enhancements,
         gets the current play volume of the player node */

```
private func installReadTapOnPadMixer(bankNumber: Int, padNumber: Int)
{
    guard(_soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber]?.tapInstalled == false) else{ return;  }

    // https://miguelsaldana.me/2017/03/18/how-to-create-a-volume-meter-in-swift-3/
    _padMixerArray[bankNumber]![padNumber]?.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: _outputFormat)
    {
        (buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer!, time: AVAudioTime!) in
            let dataptrptr = buffer.floatChannelData!;
            let dataptr = dataptrptr.pointee;
            let datum = dataptr[Int(buffer.frameLength) - 1];
            self._padMixerVolumeDataArray[bankNumber][padNumber] = fabs(datum);
    }

    _soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber]?.tapInstalled = true;
}
```

Then when I call play() in my “MasterSoundMod” class, I start a timer in order to read data from the tap like so:

/** play a pad's current sound configuration */

```
func play(bankNumber: Int, padNumber: Int, preview: Bool)
{
    if(!_isConnected && !_routeChanging)
    {
        if((_soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber]) != nil && (_soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber])!.isLoaded)
        {    

            if(!(_soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber]?.playerNodeArray[(_soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber]?.currentPlayIndex)!]!.engine?.isRunning)!)
            {
                startMod();  // start the AVAudioEngine and update a few state variables
            }

             // [[PadModel]] 
            (_soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber])!.play();
        }
    }

    // the timer must not be scheduled for any preview or any blank pad
    if(!preview)
    {
        _volumeDataTimerArray[bankNumber][padNumber] = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(updateVolumeData(timer:)), userInfo: (bankNumber, padNumber), repeats: true);
    }
}
```

Then in my selector function passed to .scheduledTimer() I have:

/** pass the currently touched pad's current volume from here,
            up to the owning Song,
                and then down the line to the PadView object that corresponds to the Pad model which is currently playing */

```
@objc func updateVolumeData(timer: Timer)
{
    let userInfo = timer.userInfo as! (Int, Int);

    _delegate!.passCurrentVolumeToPadView(bankNumber: userInfo.0, padNumber: userInfo.1, volume: _padMixerVolumeDataArray[userInfo.0][userInfo.1]); // <- EXEC_BAD_ACCESS
```

The exception is being thrown in the call to _delegate!.passCurrentVolumeToPadView()
Also, I invalidate my timers in the stop() method like so:

/** stop playing the pad corresponding to the bank and pad number */

```
func stop(bankNumber: Int, padNumber: Int)
{
    _releaseTimerArray[bankNumber][padNumber] = Timer()

    var preFadeVolume: Float = 0.0;

    if(_padMixerArray[bankNumber]![padNumber] != nil){  preFadeVolume = (_padMixerArray[bankNumber]![padNumber]?.volume)!;  }

    // no player node manipulation while audio route change is in progress.
    if(!_isConnected && !_routeChanging)
    {
        if((_soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber]) != nil && (_soundCollection[bankNumber]![padNumber])!.isLoaded)
        {
            _releaseTimerArray[bankNumber][padNumber] = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(self.fadeout(timer:)), userInfo: (bankNumber, padNumber, preFadeVolume), repeats: true);
        }

        _volumeDataTimerArray[bankNumber][padNumber]?.invalidate();
    }

    // for good measure.....
    //      this DOES need to be here!
    if(_volumeDataTimerArray[bankNumber][padNumber] != nil && (_volumeDataTimerArray[bankNumber][padNumber]!.isValid))
    {
        _volumeDataTimerArray[bankNumber][padNumber]?.invalidate();
    }
}
```

The stop() method schedules a timer to execute the sound being faded out to avoid nasty click sounds, but that is not part of this question.

I have tried a few things to fix the problem. I originally was using a single timer and a single _volumeData variable. Promoting both of these members to arrays has greatly decreased the frequency with which the exception is thrown.

Sometimes when I launch the app, I cannot get the exception to be thrown after 5 minutes of pressing pads. Other times when I launch the app, the exception will be thrown in under a minute of pressing pads.

Now, of course, the block of code in the call to installTap() in my installReadTapOnPadMixer() is run outside of my main Thread.

My naive hypothesis as to what is causing the exception is that my _padMixerVolumeDataArray[] is getting written to at the same time it is being read from. Again, this is a naive.

After looking into the problem a little more, the consensus about EXEC_BAD_ACCESS seems to be that it is thrown when you try to access an object that has been released. So perhaps a more accurate explanation is that the code in updateVolumeData() method is getting called after the corresponding timer has been invalidated……..?

Again, I know it is a lot of code to look at, but the methods that seem to be the root of the problem are the installReadTapOnPadMixer() and the updateVolumeData() methods.

Much appreciation to any body with any insight!

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint and run the project, it would stop in the line that causes the crash to happen. That would help you isolate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Well apparently I made a rookie mistake. Previously to finding my solution, the array in question was declared like so:

private lazy var _padMixerVolumeDataArray: [[Float?]?]! = [];

This ill advised declaration was in response to trying to solve various memory leak issues in my app.

After I changed the declaration and mashed my pads for 55 minutes without the exc_bad_access being thrown, I came to the conclusion that the problem was solved. The new declaration:

private var _padMixerVolumeDataArray: [[Float]] = [];

I got the idea to remove the lazy keyword from this: http://blog.swilliams.me/words/2015/03/31/tracking-down-an-exc-bad-access-with-swift/

Another similar question I did not find until the problem was solved:
[Why does my @lazy property crash, but if I make it non lazy it works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24033759/why-does-my-lazy-property-crash-but-if-i-make-it-non-lazy-it-works)